# Spring boot batch - ClassNotFoundException when starting

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have one spring boot project with 3 spring boot sub modules :

- mxm-suv-**dao**
- mxm-suv-**batch**
- mxm-suv-**ws**

The dao submodule is used by batch and ws.

In local (with eclipse), I can install/package or start theses modules, all is OK.

But, when I try to start the batch in the server with java -jar, I obtain "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.at.mxm.suv.dao.domain.Report".

**dao pom.xml :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.at.mxm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mxm-suv</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>mxm-suv-dao</artifactId>
<name>mxm-suv-dao</name>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.at.mxm.suv.dao.DataAccessApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**batch pom.xml :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.at.mxm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mxm-suv</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>mxm-suv-batch</artifactId>
<name>mxm-suv-batch</name>
<properties>
    <start-class>com.at.mxm.suv.batch.BatchApplication</start-class>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.at.mxm</groupId>
        <artifactId>mxm-suv-dao</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**BatchApplication.java :**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.at.mxm.suv.dao.*,com.at.mxm.suv.batch.*")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Any ideas what may cause this please?

Comment: why build in each sub module?

Comment: Add `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in dao pom.xml like this: `<artifactId>mxm-suv-dao</artifactId>
<name>mxm-suv-dao</name> <packaging>jar</packaging>`

Comment: @pks : If I remove build in batch, issue is the same.

Comment: @Clover : I added packaging jar, issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

refer this [git](https://github.com/pankajsewalia01/blank_spring_boot_multi_module) repository.. i have made 5 modules.

Comment: Thank you but your project is empty. I see only pom.xml and settings files.

Comment: yes, that's where you have to put your code and mvn package && java -jar or eclipse.